# How can I reduce lines of code and make it work with other data?

Tags: python, multiclass-classification, precision-recall

I have multi-classes like this:

```
predicted = [1 0 2 1 1 0 1 2 1 2 2 0 0 0 0 2 2 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 2 1 1 2 0 0]
actual    = [1 0 2 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 2 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 1 2 0 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 0]
```

And I want to find the precision for each class(0,1,2)

This is my code:

```
TP_0 = 0
TP_1 = 0
TP_2 = 0
FP_0 = 0
FP_1 = 0
FP_2 = 0
    
for i in range(len(y_pred)):
    if y_pred[i] == y_test[i] :
        if y_pred[i] == 0: 
            TP_0 += 1
        elif y_pred[i] == 1:
            TP_1 += 1
        else:
            TP_2 += 1
    else:
        if y_pred[i] == 0: 
            FP_0 += 1
        elif y_pred[i] == 1:
            FP_1 += 1
        else:
            FP_2 += 1 

precision_0 = TP_0/(TP_0+FP_0)
precision_1 = TP_1/(TP_1+FP_1)
precision_2 = TP_2/(TP_2+FP_2)
```

It works if I know the number of classes and data before.
But now I want to make it work whether or not I know them, like if I have a larger number of classes.

How can I reduce the code or make it dynamic?

Note: I don't like to finish it with a library.

Comment: What's the expected result for your example?

Comment: *"I don't like to finish it with library"* - Why not? You're even already using a library:  lists,  `range` and `len` are in Python's standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def precision(y_test, y_pred): 
    # to count false-pos and true-pos  
    classes = sorted(list(set(y_test + y_pred)))
    tp = {cls: 0 for cls in classes}
    fp = {cls: 0 for cls in classes}
    
    # count tp and fp
    for i in range(len(y_pred)):
        if y_pred[i] == y_test[i]:
            tp[y_test[i]] += 1
        else:
            fp[y_test[i]] += 1
    
    
    # calculate prec for every class
    precision = dict()
    for cls in classes:
        try:
            precision[cls] = tp[cls] / (tp[cls] + fp[cls])
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            precision[cls] = 0.0
    
    return precision


predicted = [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4]
actual = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3]
print(precision(actual, predicted))
```

**Output:**

```
{0: 0.5, 1: 0.5, 2: 0.5, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0}
```

You get dictionary with key - class and value - precision.

Comment: I was just working on a similar solution :). If you use `{i:0 for i in set(y_test + y_pred)}` for both `tp` and `fp`, this will account for the 0 precision score if a class is not predicted, and also avoid using libraries, which is one of the OP's request.

Comment: rewritten it without libraries

Comment: @Pavel Kochkin if you don't see an `import` statement, the code doesn't use libraries. (Or it tries to use libraries but it doesn't generally work because they are not imported but that's not the case here).

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly yes, sorry :((

Comment: oh i didn't see this was the same name

Comment: Anyways, the assumption that classes are identified with consecutive integers starting from zero is not very general. I'd go with `classes = list(set(y_test + y_pred)).sort()`. This works under the reasonable assumption that class identifiers are hashable.

Comment: @Joooeey, I would say it's very general indeed. In fact, most ML libraries like sklearn will assume targets are encoded like that and provide tools for encoding if they're not.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly, did I correct the error correctly?

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np

# Convert to arrays
y_pred = np.array(y_pred)
y_test = np.array(y_test)

def get_precision(pred, truth, num_classes):
    precision_by_class = []
    match = (pred == truth) # Binary array indicating whether each prediction is true
    for i_class in range(num_classes): # Iterate over classes
        # match[pred == i_class].sum() -> number of correct predictions of specific class
        # (pred == i_class).sum() -> number of times specific class was predicted
        out.append(match[pred == i_class].sum() / (pred == i_class).sum())
    accuracy = match.mean() # Total accuracy
    return precision_by_class, accuracy
```